# Is there a PostgreSQL equivalent to Oracle's analytics?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, analytics

On another thread I saw a answer to a sql problem using Oracle's analytics. Is there a equivalent in PostgreSQL or generic SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas.. and it sounds like they won't be in Postgres 8.4, either. They are under development, though.

Some useful functions can be found in this contrib: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tablefunc.html  (connect_by, crosstab)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Oracle Analytics, but I've worked with Jasper Reports a little and I like it.

- Jasper Reports is a library that you can code against to run reports.
- Jasper Server lets you host your reports in a web app. It has security and scheduling.
- iReport is a GUI designer for Jasper and it can upload reports directly to Jasper Server.
- Jasper Analysis is for Analytics.

More here: http://www.jaspersoft.com/JasperSoft_JasperServer.html

Most of the stuff is free, but there are commercial versions too.